# Colorize button sprite dynamically with GD libs

Tags: php, image, gd, colorize

In my idea I'd like to have a php function performing this function (http://www.webdesign.org/img_articles/13993/specialeffecte5.jpg) such as in Photoshop.
Parameters should be:
- Hue
- Saturation
- Lightness

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You best option would be to use something like this http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/. And then build the ability to for the Jquery to pass the colours onto A PHP GD script.